# Incorporating user feedback in a ML model

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, prediction, keras

I have developed a ML model for a classification (0/1) NLP task and deployed it in production environment. The prediction of the model is displayed to users, and the users have the option to give a feedback (if the prediction was right/wrong).

How can I continuously incorporate this feedback in my model ? From a UX stand point you dont want a user to correct/teach the system more than twice/thrice for a specific input, system shld learn fast i.e. so the feedback shld be incorporated "fast". (Google priority inbox does this in a seamless way)

How does one build this "feedback loop" using which my system can improve ? I have searched a lot on net but could not find relevant material. any pointers will be of great help.

Pls dont say retrain the model from scratch by including new data points. Thats surely not how google and facebook build their smart systems

To further explain my question - think of google's spam detector or their priority inbox or their recent feature of "smart replies". Its a well known fact that they have the ability to learn / incorporate (fast) user feed.

**All the while when it incorporates the user feedback fast (i.e. user has to teach the system correct output atmost 2-3 times per data point and the system start to give correct output for that data point) AND it also ensure it maintains old learnings and does not start to give wrong outputs on older data points (where it was giving right output earlier) while incorporating the learning from new data point.**

*I have not found any blog/literature/discussion w.r.t how to build such systems - An intelligent system that explains in detaieedback loop" in ML systems*

Hope my question is little more clear now.

Update: Some related questions I found are:

- [Does the SVM in sklearn support incremental (online) learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056460/does-the-svm-in-sklearn-support-incremental-online-learning)
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/libraries-for-online-machine-learning
- http://mlwave.com/predicting-click-through-rates-with-online-machine-learning/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift

Update: I still dont have a concrete answer but such a recipe does exists. Read the section "Learning from the feedback" in the following blog  [Machine Learning != Learning Machine](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Machine_Learning_Learning_Machine). In this Jean talks about "adding a feedback ingestion loop to machine". Same in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854131/use-feedback-or-reinforcement-in-machine-learning), [here](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2015/12/11/machine-learning-can-machines-ever-be-taught-to-think-like-us/), here[4](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43146.pdf).

Comment: It depends on how you arrived at the output model. If you used something like stochastic gradient descent or other incremental training alike, new data points can be added for more iterations.

Comment: @Mai: I have added more explanation to my question. pls read the part in **bold**

Comment: But you have not described how you trained your model...`DeepLearning is used` is probably not a description of model training process...Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Mai: Fair enough. this is using a LSTM (stateless) using word embeddings trained on dataset vocab to initialize the weights of Embedding layer.  loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam'                                          You can find the complete code here - https://github.com/anujgupta82/DeepNets/blob/master/LSTM/IMDB_Embedding_w2v_LSTM_1.ipynb

Comment: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~eckdoug/papers/2003_nn.pdf, famous paper. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a simple, light model(s) that can be updated per feedback. Online Machine learning gives a number of candidates for this

Most good online classifiers are linear. In which case we can have a couple of them and achieve non-linearity by combining them via a small shallow neural net

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126546/nonlinear-dynamic-online-classification-looking-for-an-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

There could be couple of ways to do this:

1) You can incorporate the feedback that you get from the user to only train the last layer of your model, keeping the weights of all other layers intact. Intuitively, for example, in case of CNN this means you are extracting the features using your model but slightly adjusting the classifier to account for the peculiarities of your specific user.

2) Another way could be to have a global model ( which was trained on your large training set) and a simple logistic regression which is user specific. For final predictions, you can combine the results of the two predictions. See [this paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36955.pdf) by google on how they do it for their priority inbox.